# join two queries with different where statement

Tags: php, mysql

I have two `update` queries with different `where` statements.

Is it possible to do the job with a single one?

```
$sql = "update users set light = replace(light, '" . $clicked . ",', '') where userid = :aid";
$st = $db->prepare($sql);
$st->execute([":aid" => $_SESSION['userid']]);

$sql = "update users set seen = 'seen' where userid = :aid and xfrom = :axfrom";
$st = $db->prepare($sql);
$st->execute([
    ":axfrom" => $clicked,
    ":aid" => $_SESSION['userid']
]);
```

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix, `transaction` - any example or reference, pls?

Comment: I just realized that, Sorry, I been going crosseyed updating old wordpress sites to PHP7 for the last few weeks, Stuff where the theme's/plugins are no longer maintained.  (reminds me of the PHP4-5 change over, everyone is rushing to change as they are dropping support for 5.6 in a couple months... )  Sorry !  I deleted my comments, blah blah.... sorry again.

Comment: anyway, thanks for a new word for me - `transaction`

Comment: Yea typically you would use it, for example, if you have 2 related tables, so if there is an error on the second insert/update, you can roll the change back and not do the first insert/update.  That way you don't leave partial relationships floating around  (orphans).  That was what I was thinking, that you had two different but related tables that you wanted to update at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this in a single update with the help of a `CASE` expression:

```
UPDATE users
SET
    light = REPLACE(light, ?, ''),
    seen = CASE WHEN xfrom = :axfrom THEN 'seen' ELSE seen END
WHERE userid = :aid
```

Both your updates share a portion of the same `WHERE` logic, so we can leave that `WHERE` clause as is.  For updating the `seen` column, we only make a change if the `xfrom` condition matches, otherwise we no-op.

Not sure if you should also be using a placeholder in the call to `REPLACE`, but other than this it is good that you are using prepared statements.

Comment: I gotta start using CASE more often, I hardly ever use it and often forget about it altogether.